# Hibernate SQLGrammarException on join table

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have three tables: `user`, `group` and `membership`. The `membership` table is the joining table of the users and groups as users can be a member in multiple groups and vica versa.

I have a Spring Boot application in which I would like to access the groups of a certain user.

**User class**

```
@Entity
public class User {
    /* members */

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "membership",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    )
    private Set<Group> groups;

    public Set<Group> getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }

    /* getters, setters */
}
```

**Group class**

```
@Entity
public class Group {
    /* members */

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "membership",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    )
    private Set<User> users;

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    /* getters, setters */
}
```

**Usage**

```
Integer id;

User user = userRepository.findById(id).get();

Set<Group> groups = user.getGroups();
```

When I debug the code, I get the following error:

```
Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException' exception.
```

I am a beginner to both Spring Boot and Hibernate.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the fact that I use MySQL server is important.
When displaying the raw SQL query, the `group` table is there without the special enclosing apostrophe signs. This way the MySQL server assumes that `group` is a faulty `group by` statement.

Explicitly stating the table name with the enclosing apostrophe signs solves the problem.

```
@Table(name = "`group`")
public class Group {
    /* some code */
}
```